# Maple: How to input such system so that it would be solved?

Tags: maple, computer-algebra-systems

How to input such system 
[image]
into maple so that it would solve it?

BTW we some part of system will be given to us, which we do not know certainly - may be some $A_i$'s may be some  $B_i$'s as constants. We do not know how much constants we will get. And we would need from given constants get a solution for other $a$'s and $b$'s. In real life we will be provided with $s$ as a constant but I hoped for general solution=)

Comment: So, $2k+2$ variables $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ and $s+1$ equations?

Comment: kind of so it would have to outpot parametrized solution=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want your solution be parametrized in $k,s$. I don't think Maple can
do that. What you need to do is to solve this linear system for some particular
$k, s$ and hopefully you can discern a pattern.

You can solve linear systems using the linear algebra package: >with(LinearAlgebra); or >with(linalg); the last one is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Maple questions would be better posted at mapleprimes.com but if you must know **how to input this system in Maple**, this will do:

sys := (k, s) -> {add(i*alpha[i], i = 1 .. k)-add(beta[i], i = 1 .. k), add(alpha[i], i = 0 .. k), seq(add(i^eta*alpha[i], i = 1 .. k)-add(i^(eta-1)*beta[i], i = 1 .. k), eta = 2 .. s)};

Next you can use the command *subs* to substitute the known values of the alpha_i and/or beta_i. As others pointed here: Maple *may* solve this system only if k and s are given.